# Draw line from transformed canvas to another transformed canvas

Tags: css, html5-canvas

Here I am trying to draw line between two different points on different canvas positioned using transform CSS. CSS places canvases with some angle between them
I have multiple canvases positioned  using transform properties of css,
example:

```js
 var c1=document.getElementById('c1').getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX0=c1.left;
    offsetY0=c1.top;        
    c2=document.getElementById('c2').getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX1=c2.left;
    offsetY1=c2.top;        

    var x0=10+offsetX0;
    var y0=30+offsetY0;
    var x1=60+offsetX1;
    var y1=60+offsetY1;
    var w=Math.abs(x1-x0);
    var h=Math.abs(y1-y0);

    var overlay=document.getElementById('overlay');
    overlay.width=w+2;
    overlay.height=h+2;
    overlay.style.left=(x0-1)+'px';
    overlay.style.top=(y0-1)+'px';

    var context=overlay.getContext('2d');
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(1,1);//point on canvas1
    context.lineTo(overlay.width-1,overlay.height-1);//point on canvas2
    context.lineWidth=1;
    context.stroke();
```

```css
#overlay{position:absolute;bottom:5px;pointer-events:none;border:none;}
        #container
      {
          width:500px;
          height: 340px;
       margin:80px auto;  
        position:relative;
        perspective: 3500px;
  perspective-origin:  100px -150px;
 
    }
    #shape {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    }
 
 .ready #shape {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
      -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
       transition: transform 1s;
    }
  .ready #shape canvas 
  {
      -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
         -moz-transition: opacity 1s, -moz-transform 1s;
           -o-transition: opacity 1s, -o-transform 1s;
              transition: opacity 1s, transform 1s;
    }
  #shape canvas 
  {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 500px;
      height: 340px;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
      line-height: 116px;
      font-size: 80px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: green;
      text-align: center;
   
    }
 #shape 
 {
      border: 1px;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }
 .ring {
      position: absolute;
     
      width: 500px;
    height:340px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Times, serif;
      font-size: 124pt;
      color: black;
      background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }
 .ring > .r1
 {
 translateZ(-144px);
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(-250px);
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 1;
 }
 .ring > .r2
 {
 translateZ(-144px);
    transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(-250px);
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 1;
 }
 .ring > .r3
 {
 translateZ(-144px);
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(-250px);
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="ready"> 
 
 <div id="container">
 
   
    <div id="shape" class="ring" class="panels-backface-invisible">
 <canvas id="c1" class="ring r1" width="500" height="340"></canvas>
 <canvas id="c2" class="ring r2"></canvas>
 
     </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <canvas id="overlay"></canvas>
```

But when drawing, it does not match points specified on canvas and line drawn between points because canvas is transformed.

Comment: u mean u want to connect points specified on canvas and line drawn ?

Comment: I have to draw line between two points on different canvas ,In which one point is on first canvas and other point is on second canvas .Canvases are transformed using css.

Comment: i am not sure, that this is wat u want, as per ur code, u r using var x0=10+offsetX0;
    var y0=30+offsetY0; where 10 and 30 moves out of ur point, just try var x0=0+offsetX0;
    var y0=0+offsetY0;.

Comment: Trying to draw line between p1(10,30) on canvas1 and p2(60,60) on canvas2,to do this I need to draw third canvas on top of two canvases. so I got two points (left offset of canvas1+10,top offset of canvas1+10) and (left offset of canvas2+60,top offset of canvas2+60) to draw line between them. But in case of second canvas which is transformed using rotate(270) and translateZ(-250) didn't got correct position because that canvas is transformed